# What does '_' do in Django code?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

Why does this Django code use `_` in front of 'has favicon'

```
has_favicon = models.BooleanField(_('has favicon'))
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you look in the import statements, you'll find that they tied _ to a function that turns stuff into unicode and localizes it by writing:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: For those seeing this answer, Django has deprecated `ugettext_lazy` in favor of `gettext_lazy`.

Answer (score 11):

`_` in Django is a convention that is used for localizing texts. It is an alias for ugettext_lazy. Read [Lazy translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation) in the docs for more info about it.

Answer (score 9):

`_` is usually a macro/function from gettext,  it means the argument is a localized string.  this is not limited to Django or Python.  in fact gettext is originally a package for C programs, ported to many other languages over the years.

Comment: added part about gettext heritage.  you can copy it as well. ;)

Comment: It also marks it as needing translation so automated tools can create a *.po file for translators to use.