# AssertionError: ValidationError not raised by full_clean

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-forms

In the following form, I have declared a `clean()` method that is evaluating the following condition:

*Does the the `expiration_date` come before the the `created_date`?*

If the that condition is True, I want to raise a *ValidationError*. When the test is ran, I get the following error: `AssertionError: ValidationError not raised by full_clean`.

However if `form.errors.as_data()` is called, this results in: `{'expiration_date': [ValidationError(['The expiration date is set before the created date'])]}`

Could some explain as to what is happening?

**forms.py**

```
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    MENU_YEARS = [2019, 2020, 2021]

    season = forms.CharField(
        min_length=4, 
        validators=[validate_season]
    )
    items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Item.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='name'
    )
    expiration_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        required=False,
        widget=SelectDateWidget(
            years=MENU_YEARS,
            empty_label=("Choose Year", "Choose Month", "Choose Day")
        )
    )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        created_date = cleaned_data['created_date'] = timezone.now()
        expiration_date = cleaned_data['expiration_date']
        if created_date > expiration_date:
            raise ValidationError(
               {'expiration_date': "The expiration date is set before the created date"}
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['season', 'items', 'expiration_date']
```

**test_forms.py**

```
class TestMenuForm(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.data = {
            'season': 'Late Fall',
            'items': ['Crepe'],
            'expiration_date': datetime(2018, 1, 2)
        }

    def test_menu_model_clean(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            self.menu_form.full_clean()
```

Comment: See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror), the way you're passing params to `ValidationError` isn't what the docs show. Did you try following that? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962289/6388133 if you need to import `_`

Comment: I fixed the Validation Error to: `ValidationError(_("Invalid Expiration"), code="invalid_expiration")`, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Marcell answer is valid I do not think this is the reason for the behaviour you are experiencing.

As far as I know when calling `full_clean` on a `ModelForm` the `clean` method is called too, but `ValidationErrors` are caught internally and the error is added to `form.errors`. So your test does not get to "see" this error. This is what your currently seeing in your test. IMHO this behaviour makes sense as you probably do not want your app to stop on a validation error.

To test your `ValidationError` you might want to call the forms `clean` method directly instead of `full_clean`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the cleaned data

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    created_date = cleaned_data['created_date'] = timezone.now()
    expiration_date = cleaned_data['expiration_date']
    if created_date > expiration_date:
        raise ValidationError(
           {'expiration_date': "The expiration date is set before the created date"}
        )
    return cleaned_data
```